# Rails how to reload view after job status is completed?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am working on a test project where someone enters a Url into a form and I use an Active Job to retrieve the open graph protocol preview image, and then I want to reload the page using javascript to show the image once the job is done running.

I have everything working except the reload:

Controller:

```rb
def open_graph_preview
  @new_preview = Preview.new
  @preview = Preview.last
  # sends newly created Preview to Job
  @job = FindOpenGraphImageJob.perform_later(@preview)
  # begins status check on currently running Job
  @job_status = ActiveJobStatus.fetch(@job.job_id)
end
```

Job:

```rb
def perform(preview)
  # Uses Faraday to get all info on the given URL
  response = Faraday.get(preview.url)
  # Uses OGP gem to parse the meta data from Faraday response
  open_graph = OGP::OpenGraph.new(response.body)

  @preview = Preview.find(preview.id)
  # Updates the image_url with the open graph image url
  @preview.update_attribute :image_url, open_graph.image.url
end
```

View:

```html
<h1>Open Graph Protocol Preview</h1>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <%= form_with(model: @new_preview, local: true) do |form| %>

    <div class="field form-group">
      <%= form.label :url %>
      <%= form.text_field :url, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions form-group">
      <%= form.submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center" style="padding:50px;">
  <img src="<%= @preview.image_url %>">
</div>
```

Could someone please help me figure out how to use javascript to check the `@job_status` in the controller, and reload the page when `@job_status.completed?`?

Comment: This is a very broad question. I'm not sure you're going to get the help you're looking for. In general, the way I do something like this is: (1) attach an `on ajax:success` handler on my form, (2) submit the form via js and return a status-tracking modal, (3) load the modal using the attached handler, (4) the modal polls for job status (using a spinner or some other visual widget to indicate polling/progress), (5) when job is complete, modal fetches HTML blob and loads in DOM.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it's a frustrating problem because it doesn't seem like it should be so broad or complicated. But the more I'm understanding the scope of the problem, the more I get how complicated it is.

Comment: Yep, I hear you. The Q&A format isn't always the greatest for the stage you appear to be at. LMK if you get hung up on something particular or want to kick it around a little - I could open a chat and give a little time if it would help.

Comment: Thanks, thats amazing. I am currently trying to use ActionCable to solve the issue, but if that doesn't work, I will definitely take you up on that.

Comment: Roger that. ActionCable was too big of a jump for me at this point, so I've shied away from it. But, go for it!!!